# Connect to SQL Server database by putting database file on One drive or google drive

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

This might sound like a wierd question but is it possible to put the SQL Server db file i.e. mdf file in Google drive or OneDrive folder and then connect my application to this database using sql server instance installed on my two different PCs?

Actually I have two PCs. Both have google drive and one drive installed. So I want to use my application on both PCs that connect to same database.

Comment: No, for many reasons, the main one being that services such as those mentioned use caches not realtime updates to a shared source.  SQL Server is a server, you would set it up somewhere with a public IP address (or via VPN) and connect the clients to it that way.

Comment: Perfect answer, but seriously, that was the oddest phrased question I've ever read on StackOverflow...  ;-)